# why does the series converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I try to solve this problem and I used mean value theorem for 3 times and get maybe the better equation but I dont know what should I do in this step!(after using 3 times mean value theorem).
**problem** :
Suppose that f(x) is defined on [−1, 1] and that its third derivative exists and
is continuous. (That is, f is of class C3.) Prove that the series
$$\sum_{n=0} (n(f(1/n) - f(-1/n)) - 2f'(0))$$ 
converges.

Comment: Apply Taylor's theorem (with Lagrange's form of the remainder) to $f$.

Comment: oh thanks!easily solved with Taylor's theorem.